# Set form inputs based on json object

Tags: jquery, json

In my code I have a JSON serialized dictionary like so:

```
{ BackgroundColor="F4F4F4", ShowTitle=true, NumberToShow=10}
```

I need to set the values of matching form fields (using the property key).

Here's how I'm doing it currently:

```
    function applyPreset(preset) {
        for (var prop in preset) {
            var $container = $("div#attribute-" + prop);
            $("input", $container).val(preset[prop]);
        }
    }
```

This works fine for textboxes but obviously doesn't work for radio checkboxes or select lists.

I wondered if there were any clever functions in jQuery to do this or should I just loop through each input, check it's type and set the value accordingly?

Comment: So it seems the answer is to effectively check each input type. Shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(":radio", $container).attr('checked',preset[prop]);
$("select", $container).val(preset[prop]).change();
```

for checkbox

```
$(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

**OR**

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

should work.

Comment: the checkbox doesn't appear to work with the true/false values.

Comment: Yeh, that's working for me now, problem was the cast. Is this the correct way to cast ==> `if (typeof presetValue == "boolean") {
                    $(":checkbox", $container).attr("checked", Boolean(presetValue));
                }`

Comment: @Ben in this case what is your presetValue. do they like true/false or  1/0 or something else.

Comment: They are true/false. The code I posted works fine, just wondered if this the best way of checking.